# What Pokemon were revealed before their generation was announced?

Tags: pokemon-series

Title, basically. There's lists of what pokemon were shown in the anime early before the anime moved to the relevant region, But I'm asking for cases like Bonsly (who was first revealed in XD in August 2005, but Diamond and Pearl were announced in 2006).

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "announced"? For example, Ho-oh was shown in the first episode of Pokemon, but didn't actually make an appearance until the second generation as an actual Pokemon.

Comment: Do you need a full list or just a "large enough" List as an answer ?

Comment: As said by @Ben, there are a lot of pokemon that were revealed/announced before they were available ingame (Ho-oh and Togepi for example in the 1st anime arc, Zoroark in Gen 5 trailer and more recently Sirfetch'd for Sword-Shield)

Answer (score 1):

There was the statues of G4 Pokemon in Mystery Dungeon Red and Blue (Nov 2005) which featured Pokemon from G1-3 and after a quick check, Mystery Dungeon was released before Diamond and Pearl (Sept 2006)

So there's Lucario, Weavile, Mime Junior, and Bonsly revealed before their main game appearance.